# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. What's the best practice for mapping multiple onetoone references

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Product Entity which has various `@OneToOne` mapping with `Brand`, `Category` and `Inventory` Entity. Mapping's are given as under.
When I do `session.add(product)`. I get error stating 
**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`product_new_1`, CONSTRAINT `FK42A97DC2A483B29F` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_CATEGORY`) REFERENCES `CATEGORY_NEW_1` (`CATEGORY_ID`))**

To overcome this I did

```
session.add(category); 
session.add(brand);
session.add(inventory);
session.add(product1);
```

all in one transactional scope.

**Should not hibernate take care of related entities like(inventory, category, brand) when an referencing entity is persisted like product ?**

**Product**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PRODUCT_NEW_1")
    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
        private String productName;

        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION")
        private String productDescription;

        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_PRICE")
        private Number productPrice;

        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_FOR_GENDER")
        private char productForGender; // M F U

        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_DISCOUNT")
        private String productDiscount;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_BRAND")
        private Brand brand;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY")
        private Category category;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_INVENTORY")
        private Inventory inventory;

        // @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_CATEGORY", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =
        // "PRODUCT_REFERENCE_KEY", nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        // @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "CATEGORY_REFERENCE_ID") })

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public Brand getBrand() {
            return brand;
        }

        public void setBrand(Brand brand) {
            this.brand = brand;
        }

        public String getProductDescription() {
            return productDescription;
        }

        public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
            this.productDescription = productDescription;
        }

        public Number getProductPrice() {
            return productPrice;
        }

        public void setProductPrice(Number productPrice) {
            this.productPrice = productPrice;
        }

        public Inventory getInventory() {
            return inventory;
        }

        public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
            this.inventory = inventory;
        }

        public char getProductForGender() {
            return productForGender;
        }

        public void setProductForGender(char productForGender) {
            this.productForGender = productForGender;
        }

        public String getProductDiscount() {
            return productDiscount;
        }

        public void setProductDiscount(String productDiscount) {
            this.productDiscount = productDiscount;
        }

        public Category getCategory() {
            return category;
        }

        public void setCategory(Category category) {
            this.category = category;
        }

    }
```

**Brand** 
    package main.java.domain;

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="BRAND_NEW")
public class Brand {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BRAND_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "BRAND_NAME")
    private String brandName;

    @Column(name = "BRAND_DESCRIPTION")
    private String brandDescription;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Product.class,mappedBy="brand", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Product product;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    public String getBrandDescription() {
        return brandDescription;
    }

    public void setBrandDescription(String brandDescription) {
        this.brandDescription = brandDescription;
    }

}
```

**Category**

```
package main.java.domain;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY_NEW_1")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION")
    private String categoryDescription;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Product.class, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Product product;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getCategoryDescription() {
        return categoryDescription;
    }

    public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
        this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

**Inventory** 
    package main.java.domain;

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "INVENTORY_NEW")
public class Inventory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INVENTORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "QUANT_AVAILABLE")
    private long quantityAvailable;

    @Column(name = "QUANT_REQUIRED")
    private long quantityRequired;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity= Product.class, mappedBy = "inventory", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
    private Product product;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getQuantityAvailable() {
        return quantityAvailable;
    }

    public void setQuantityAvailable(long quantityAvailable) {
        this.quantityAvailable = quantityAvailable;
    }

    public long getQuantityRequired() {
        return quantityRequired;
    }

    public void setQuantityRequired(long quantityRequired) {
        this.quantityRequired = quantityRequired;
    }
}
```

and this is **controller** that handles `addProduct request`.

```
        Brand brand = new Brand();
        brand.setBrandName("LEVIS");
        brand.setBrandDescription("DENIM BRAND OWNED BY ARVIND MILL");

        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        inventory.setQuantityAvailable(5);
        inventory.setQuantityRequired(0);

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(10l);
        category.setCategoryDescription("ELECTRONICS MOBILE CATEGORY");
        category.setCategoryName("Lucida Grande;N;12");

        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setProductDescription("MOTO X SNAP DRAGON 8 MP CAMERA");
        product1.setProductDiscount("0");
        product1.setProductForGender('U');
        product1.setProductPrice(13000);
        product1.setProductName("MOTO X 16 GB");
        product1.setBrand(brand);
        product1.setCategory(category);
        product1.setInventory(inventory);
//      loginService.add(category,inventory, brand, product1);
        loginService.add(product1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will execute one by one query at run time based on our save method order. Because of that only you are getting this error. If you want to give responsibility to hibernate then use 'Cascad' then hibernate will persist all of your child entity first then it will persist main entity.